# How to change position of output panel in sublime text?

Tags: ide, window, sublimetext, text-editor

I want the output to show to the right of the code, not bellow it. I can change the view to two columns but I can't change the position of the output panel. For example:

[image]

Is it possible to change the position of the output panel to be to the right of the code, not below it?

Comment: In the future, please only ask one question per question.

Comment: I found the answer to the second question so I deleted it.

Answer (score 30):

There is a solution, which exists for years already, but does not seem to be widely used. It's the package `buildview`: it puts the build output in any other view, i.e. acts as a normal tab.

LINK:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/sublime-text-2-buildview
(perfectly works with sublime 3)

Comment: With sublime open, execute 'ctrl' + 'shift' + 'p', then search for 'Package Control: Install Package', then type 'buildview', hit 'enter', restart sublime after it installs.

Comment: At least in a project of js and html files, there's no build. I can see how this answers things if you have a build process, but what about the more general case of putting all console output there? Is there an easy trick I'm missing?

Comment: @ruffin for scripted languages there is sublime-REPL (which i strongly recommend you to try out). For instance, it supports js and node, in a way a proper IDE would do. Not sure about html.

Comment: For anyone using `buildview`: the original build panel can be disabled by setting "show_panel_on_build" to false in the user settings.

Comment: Great on sublime 3. Output on new tab now.

Comment: Outputs to a new tab ON TOP OF the file being built. How do you tell it to use the empty panel to the right?

Comment: @Elliot for me it usually opens a new tab and then for each consequent build reuses it. So I switch into a two-pane view (or two windows or whatever), *move* the newly created "build-view-tab" there and get my "code-on-the-left-build-results-on-the-right" workflow. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this feature has been requested: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/23694-ability-to-show-console-output-side-by-side-with-code/. So the answer would be no, there's no way to currently do this, and there doesn't seem to be mention of it in the [changelog](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) thus far for SublimeText3.

Comment: There are heaps of plugins for sublime text, which made me think that there is a plugin for this for sure. Is it technically difficult to write a program that does this?

Comment: @user2357 - plugins can only do what the API allows them to do, and in this case there is no build panel API.