# SublimeText 3 send build result to fixed column in layout

Tags: sublimetext3

This question is *similar* to this one [How to change position of output panel in sublime text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444125/how-to-change-position-of-output-panel-in-sublime-text) but not quite the same.

I've followed the steps given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/1391441) to correctly set up a `virtualenv` to build a file, which works perfectly. The results (after building) always open in a new tab, what differs is the position of this tab depending on the layout used.

If a single column view is used, the tab opens (obviously) in that column. If two columns are used, the new tab opens *again* in the first column. If a three column layout is used, it now opens in the *third* column (?).

This behavior is inconsistent, and I would like some control over it. Is there a way to select in which column I want the new build tab to show?